# Read from file and find specific lines

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, split

I need to fetch information in settings a file (I can't change the format) according to certain keywords. The file goes like this:

```
username=myusername
address=156a1355e3486f4
data=function(i){if (i!=0) return true; else return false;}
```

The system is `<key>` `=` `<value>` `\n`. There can be `=`, spaces or other characters in the value part, but never line breaks. Keys are unique (in the "key part", they can appear in values, but `\nkey=` appears only once in the file for every key).

With a shell script, I find my values like this:

```
username=`grep ^username file.txt | sed "s/^username=//"`
```

Grep will return `username=someusername` and sed replaces the key and `=` with nothing, leaving only the value.

In node.js, I would like to access *some* of the data in the file. For example, I want the value for address and data.

How could I do this in node.js ? After `fs.readFile(file.txt)` I don't know what to do. I guess I will have to use `split`, but using `\n` doesn't seem to be the best option, maybe regex can help ?

The ideal thing would be to "find a substring starting with `\nkey=` and ending with the first `\n`", then I could easily split to find the value.

Comment: Do you want to parse it into an object? That would be easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// @text is the text read from the file.
// @key is the key to find its value
function getValueByKey(text, key){
    var regex = new RegExp("^" + key + "=(.*)$", "m");
    var match = regex.exec(text);
    if(match)
        return match[1];
    else
        return null;
}
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
// text should be obtained using fs.readFile...
var text = "username=myusername\naddress=156a1355e3486f4\ndata=function(i){if (i!=0) return true; else return false;}";


function getValueByKey(text, key){
    var regex = new RegExp("^" + key + "=(.*)$", "m");
    var match = regex.exec(text);
    if(match)
        return match[1];
    else
        return null;
}

console.log("adress: ", getValueByKey(text, "address"));
console.log("username: ", getValueByKey(text, "username"));
console.log("foo (non exist): ", getValueByKey(text, "foo"));
```

Comment: Thanks ! I knew regex was the way to go. Writing my question helped me find a solution (not as clean and adaptable as yours), using `text.match(regex)`, writing the "ideal thing" part pretty much gave me the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` and `reduce`, you can do something like that :

```
fs.readFile('file.txt', { encoding : 'utf8' }, data => {
  const settings = data
    .split('\n')
    .reduce((obj, line) => {
      const splits = line.split('=');
      const key = splits[0];
      if (splits.length > 1) {
        obj[key] = splits.slice(1).join('=');
      }
      return obj;
    }, {});
  // ...
});
```

Your settings will be stored as key/value in the `settings` object.