# Read from config file in scripts section in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

Is there a possibility to read from a config file within the `"scripts"` section in package.json?

Background of the question:
We are several developers who all work on the same terminal server. And we have a the following section in our package.json

```
...
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 8080"
}
...
```

Since we are on the same server we need a way to specify a different port. One possibility is to use a command line parameter. But i would appreciate an "easier" way where i can store a port in a config file which i add to `.gitignore`, so that every developer can have his own file and we can just type `npm run serve` without thinking about to enter a port.

Maybe there is a better way of doing what i want. I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *One possibility is to use a command line parameter.*

Yes, for that you'll need to configure your `serve` script in *package.json* like this:

```json
"scripts": {
  "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port"
}
```

Then via you CLI tool run:

```
npm run serve -- <port_number>
```

<sub>**Note:** the `<port_number>` argument should replaced with a real port number, e.g. `8080`, `3000` etc ...</sub>

---

> *...I would appreciate an "easier" way where I can store a port in a config file ...*

**The config file:**

Let's say we have a file arbitrarily named `.portnumber` which is saved in the root of the project directory. For example:

```
.
├── .gitignore
├── .portnumber    <------ 
├── node_modules
│   └── ...
├── package.json
└── ...
```

and the contents of the `.portnumber` file contains the port number to be used only. For example:

```
3000
```

---

### Solution A: **Nix platforms only (Linux/MacOS...)*

When running npm scripts on **nix* platforms the default shell that npm utilizes is `sh`. Therefore the following will work.

**package.json**

```json
"scripts": {
  "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port \"$(<.portnumber)\""
}
```

The `$(<.portnumber)` part above essentially reads the contents of the `.portnumber` file, (that's what the `<.portnumber` part does), and utilizes [command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

So given that the `.portnumber` file contains `3000` the command being executed in the npm script is effectively:

```
vue-cli-service serve --port 3000
```

You could also do this:

**package.json**

```json
"scripts": {
  "serve-with-default": "port=$(<.portnumber); vue-cli-service serve --port \"${port:-8080}\""
}
```

This is very similar to the previous, however if the `.portnumber` file did not exist or was empty, it would default to using `8080` for the port number.

---

### Solution B: Cross Platform (Windows/Linux/macOS...)

For a cross platform solution, (i.e. one that runs successfully on Windows, Linux, and macOS...), you'll need to utilize nodejs to achieve your requirement. There are a couple of different ways to approach this as described in the following two sub-sections titled:

- Using an external nodejs (.js) file
- Inlining your JavaScript in *package.json*.

#### Using an external nodejs (.js) file

Create a file named `serve.js`

**serve.js**

```js
const readFileSync = require('fs').readFileSync;
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

const port = readFileSync('.portnumber', {encoding: 'utf8'});

execSync('vue-cli-service serve --port ' + port, {stdio: 'inherit'})
```

.. and also save it in your project directory:

```
.
├── .gitignore
├── .portnumber    <------ 
├── node_modules
│   └── ...
├── package.json
├── serve.js       <------ 
└── ...
```

Redefine your `serve` npm script as follows:

**package.json**

```json
"scripts": {
  "serve": "node serve"
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `serve.js` file essentially does the following:

- Utilizes the node.js built-in [`readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) to read the contents of the `.portnumber` file and assigns the number to the `port` variable.
- Then utilizes the node.js built-in [`execSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) to run the `vue-cli-service serve --port` command with the port number that was previously read from the `.portnumber` file.

#### Inlining your JavaScript in package.json.

Alternatively, you can inline your nodejs/JavaScript code in the scripts section of your package.json instead. In which case redefine your npm script as follows:

**package.json**

```json
"scripts": {
  "serve" : "node -e \"require('child_process').execSync('vue-cli-service serve --port ' + require('fs').readFileSync('.portnumber', {encoding: 'utf8'}), {stdio: 'inherit'})\""
}
```

**Explanation:**

- This is effectively the same, (albeit refactored), as the aforementioned solution that utilized a separate `.js` file, however the use of a separate nodejs script/file is now redundant.
- The nodejs command line option [`-e`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_e_eval_script) is utilized to evaluate the inline JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! All the other answers do work as well. But this is the accepted answer just for beauty of it. It's like a missing piece of documentation on npmjs.org

Comment: Thanks. I've modified a little your `package.json` answser for a Flask python `config.py`. `"serve" : "node -e \"require('child_process').execSync('vue-cli-service serve --port ' + RegExp('^PORT_DEV=(.*)$', 'm').exec(require('fs').readFileSync('../server/config.py', {encoding: 'utf8'}))[1] , {stdio: 'inherit'})\"",` where config.py has `PORT_DEV=myport`. For read a config file [Read from file and find specific lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41767642/10489562).

Answer (score 4):

You can do all kinds of things, because npm is just running the command in a subshell.

For example, in Bash (or similar), you can use a config file:

```
$ cat config.env
PORT=8080
```

And then source the file before running the actual command:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "source config.env && vue-cli-service serve --port $PORT"
}
```

Or, in Windows, you can use a batch file:

```
C>type config.cmd
set PORT=8080
```

And then run the batch file before running the actual command:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "config.cmd && call vue-cli-service serve --port %^PORT%"
}
```

Note the weird `call` and `%^PORT%` syntax, that's not a typo. In Windows this is required to delay expansion of the variable.

Or, to make it more portable, use a Python/Node.js/whatever script.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to add a *.npmrc* file in the root directory of the project and specify a different port for each developers:

```
port=8081
```

Then you can use this variable in your app (`process.env.npm_config_port`) or *package.json*:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port $npm_config_port"
}
```

By following your idea, you could add *.npmrc* to *.gitignore*.

An even cleaner way in my opinion would be to add *.npmrc* directly in the home directory of each developers, with a specific configuration for the project.

Comment: When running on Windows the default shell that npm utilizes for npm scripts is `cmd`, in which case referencing the the `npm_config_port` variable with a `$` prefix will fail. If `cmd` is being used you'll need to use `%npm_config_port%` instead. For cross-platform consider using [cross-var](https://github.com/elijahmanor/cross-var).

Comment: Thanks for the precision for Windows `cmd` @RobC.